# Integrate type script with java controller

Tags: typescript, primeng

I am new to `PrimeNG`. I have read this [article](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).

Now, I want to try integrate primeNG datatable with springboot as back end.
In the documentation only mention about `.html and typescript (.ts)`

I take this example from above mentioned article link.

.ts

```
export class DataTableDemo implements OnInit {

cars: Car[];

cols: any[];

constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars = cars);

    this.cols = [
        {field: 'vin', header: 'Vin'},
        {field: 'year', header: 'Year'},
        {field: 'brand', header: 'Brand'},
        {field: 'color', header: 'Color'}
    ];
}
}
```

So, how about java controller? How to integrate typescript (.ts) with java controller (.java)?

Comment: Why should your datatable care what language the server backend is written in? The data should be fetched via an (asynchronous) network connection (usually a REST API) in which case your frontend does not know anything about the backend's environment

Comment: Oke, thank you @Kukeltje

Comment: @UnholySheep Beforehand I think primeng like primefaces. After read some articles, now I understand primeng is client side.